# Energy transfer between oscillators

Tags: energy, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, power

Suppose I have two mechanical oscillators $a(t), b(t)$, coupled through the interaction $V_\text{int} = \mu^2 a(t) b(t)$. Is there a simple way to express the rate of energy transfer from $a$ to $b$ using only $V_\text{int}$? Something like $\partial_t V_\text{int}$ would have the correct units, but it is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, and therefore cannot represent energy transfer from $a$ to $b$. Something like $a\partial_t(\partial_a V) - b\partial_t(\partial_b V)$ is antisymmetric under $a\leftrightarrow b$, but I can't figure out how to justify this expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually extremely simple. The power transfer between oscillators is just the time derivative of the work done on $a$ by $b$, minus the work done by $b$ on $a$
\begin{align}
P &= \frac{dW_{a\to b} - dW_{b\to a}}{d t}\,,\\
W_{a\to b}-W_{b\to a}&=\int{\rm d}a \partial_b V_\text{int} - \int{\rm d}b \partial_a V_\text{int}\,.
\end{align}
Changing integration variables from $a$ and $b$ to $t$ using the chain rule
\begin{align}
{\rm d}a = \frac{da}{dt}{\rm d t}\,,\hspace{1cm} {\rm d}b = \frac{d b}{dt}{\rm d}t\,,
\end{align}
we arrive at the following expression for the power
\begin{align}
P = (\dot a\partial_b  - \dot b\partial_a)V_\text{int}\,,
\end{align}
regardless of the form of $V_\text{int}$.